Celery-Flask Don't add records with async feature
Celery tasks don't save records to database in Flask. I don't know if i messed up configuration or have some different problem. I cant add async users to database. I don't have any errors. it jus doesn't add records to database. I add some essential code lines and I leave my repository with full code https://github.com/Sajmon9696/Celery
i tried different databases, adding celery.set_default(), flask_app.app_context().push() function, using @shared_task and @celery.task decorator
def make_celery(app: Flask) -> Celery:
    class FlaskTask(Task):
        def __call__(self, *args: object, **kwargs: object) -> object:
            with self.app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker=app.config['CELERY']['broker_url'],
        backend=app.config['CELERY']['result_backend'],
        include=['tasks']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config['CELERY'])
    celery.Task = FlaskTask
    celery.Task.app = app  # Bind the Flask app to the task class
    return celery

def create_app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db',
        CELERY=dict(
            broker_url="redis://localhost:6379/0",
            result_backend="redis://localhost:6379/0",
            task_ignore_result=True,
        ),
    )
    app.config.from_prefixed_env()

    # Initialize SQLAlchemy
    db.init_app(app)

    # Initialize Celery
    celery = make_celery(app)
    celery.set_default()



    return app, celery

flask_app, celery_app = create_app()
flask_app.app_context().push()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=True)

@shared_task
def add_users_async(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        username = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=8))
        email = f"{username}@example.com"
        user = User(username=username, email=email)
        db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return f"Added {n} users to the database." 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with flask_app.app_context():
        result = add_users_async.delay(100)
        print("Task to add 100 users has been triggered.")
        print(f"Task ID: {result.id}")``` 

